# 'string' is not assignable to type 'T' (Template type with out extends anyting)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I just looking into this for a long time but can't figure it out,
`Where is the problem?`

It's just a typescript error but compiled js work fine.

plz anyone help me with this.

here is the code

```js
type AppThemeProparty = {
   [key: string]: <T>(props: AppThemeProps<{}>) => T;
}

function getThemeProparty<U extends AppThemeProparty>(obj: U): U {
  return obj
}

export const appTheme = getThemeProparty( { 
  primaryColor: (p) => p.theme.primary, // error
  secondaryColor: (p) => p.theme.secondary, // error
})
```

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wXk6VW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: After you provide a definition for `AppThemeProps` (or, more desirably, remove your example code's dependence on it)...  could you explain why you've used so many generics here?  What purpose do they serve?  The error is because any function of a type like `<T>() => T` is impossible to safely implement; it claims to be able to return a value of any type `T` that the caller specifies, without even being given a value of type `T`.  You can use type assertions to suppress errors in such cases, but what's the point of this code?

Comment: I have changed ` <T>(...) => T ` to `(...) =>  any` it just work as I want with type safety. Thanks for trying .

Comment: The `any` type doesn't provide any type safety, so I'm a little concerned about what you're doing.  But without more detailed information I can't really help.  Good luck.